# Строгий алиасинг в MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, mingw, mingw-w64

При компиляции с MinGW-w64 этого простого кода:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void readWithSep(){
    std::istringstream sLine;
    sLine.str("hello");
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(sLine, line)){
        std::cout<<line;
    }
}

int main(){
    readWithSep<char>();
}
```

выдаётся ошибка:

> доступ по указателю с приведением типа нарушает правила перекрытия
>   объектов в памяти [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
>
> while(std::getline(sLine, line)){

Компилирую так:

> i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -std=c++17 -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -O3
>   file.cpp

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как её исправить? Здесь же вроде никаких преобразований типов не происходит. Странно, что g++ это компилирует без ошибок (с теми же флагами)

Полный вывод компилятора:

> file.cpp: В функции «void readWithSep()»:
>
> file.cpp:10:35: ошибка:
>   доступ по указателю с приведением типа нарушает правила перекрытия
>   объектов в памяти [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
>
> while(std::getline(sLine, line)){
>
> cc1plus: все предупреждения считаются ошибками

Comment: А если `while(...)` заменить на `auto& x = getline(...); while (x) { ... berak;}` в каком месте компилятор будет ругаться?

Comment: i686-w64-mingw32-g++ версии 7.1 ?

Comment: @KoVadim версия 7.1.1

Comment: да, только эта ветка gcc так ругается. 6.х или 7.2 молчат

Comment: @Abyx я же написал, на строчке `while(std::getline(sLine, line)){ ` , то есть на 10й

Comment: при этом не просто версия нужна, а ещё и оптимизация O2/O3

Comment: @ffk тогда вообще нет ошибки. `auto& x = std::getline(sLine, line);  while (x) {std::cout<<line; break;}`

Comment: @Abyx привёл полный вывод компилятора

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, это бага (точнее регресия) в gcc. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80633

Воспроисводится только при включенном -O2/-O3, потому что на этом уровне включается `-ftrict-aliasing`. Если компилятор менять не получается или уровень оптимизации, то можно просто добавить `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: Спасибо, я пока так и сделал.